# How can I send text value from ViewHolder to ItemTouchHelper class?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I've been learning Java and Android Development for about a month. Maybe, I don't know some features... But I can't find any advise for a week.
I need to send value from one of my fields in ViewHolder (created by onBindViewHolder) to overrided method onChildDraw (in class, that extends ItemTouchHelper). But I can't understand, how can I do this.
I want to call new activity after swipe action and send value of field "name" to that activity. Can I do this with Intent? Or maybe have other way?

Creating ViewHolder (public class ModelsDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ModelsViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ModelsData model = models.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(model.getName()); // <-- I NEED THIS VALUE
    holder.tags.setText(model.getTags());
    holder.keywords.setText(model.getKeywords());
    holder.cost.setText(model.getCost().toString());

    //-- some code --//
}
```

My onChildDraw (public class SwipeControl extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback):

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

    //-- some code --//

    int x = 0;
    if (dX < -200){ //
        viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_foreground).setTranslationX(dX / 3);
    } else if (dX > 200){
        viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_foreground).setTranslationX(dX / 3);
        openStatCard();
    } else if (dX == 0){
        checkActivity = false;
    }
}
```

Opening new activity (inside SwipeControl.class):

```
private void openStatCard(){
    if (!checkActivity) {
        checkActivity = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StatCards.class);
        intent.putExtra("choosingModel", model); // <-- PUT "name" IN "model"
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use to interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `onChildDraw` method use **viewHolder.getAdapterPositon()** method to get the position. And when you need the value just use that position to find `Name` from the `models` list

**EDIT**

Inside `onChildDraw` get the TextView using `viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);` and then use `getText()` method to get the Name.

Comment: I guess, I understood this wrong. Or maybe I explained my situation not quite good. Because, I can't do this. My methods **onBindViewHolder** and **onChildDraw** locate in different classes. For **onBindViewHolder** - *public class ModelsDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ModelsDataAdapter.ModelsViewHolder>*. And for **onChildDraw** - *public class SwipeControl extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback*

Comment: @MikhailShport I have modified my answer a bit to meet your requirement. Let me know if it helps

Comment: It's amazing! Thank you!